# Visualizing hierarchical distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have some distribution data, which is hierarchical. Something like this.

My lifle is:

- 40% work

  - 10 % Paper work
  - 10 % Meetings
  - 20 % programming

    - 17 % debugging
    - 3 % writing new code
- 30% sleep

  - 28 % snorring
  - 2 % normal sleep
- 30% fun

  - 2% sports
  - 28 % TV

You get the idea. What is a good way to visualize this? Is there something like a hierachical pie chart?

I would prefer to do it in python and matplotlib, but I am open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple concentric "donut" plots, but since you have different number of "layers", I don't know how that would turn out

see this page for an example: https://python-graph-gallery.com/163-donut-plot-with-subgroups/
[image]

I would probably do it the other way around, with the inner donut being your three main categories, and then breaking down each in an outward fashion